# How scaling page associated with the media-queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

How scaling page associated with the media-queries ?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
body { background-color: blue; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
body { background-color: green; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
body { background-color: orange; }
}
```

I start to play with the zoom page in a browser and I trigger different queries rules ... What is the reason this effect? My Screen size is not 500px!

Comment: Do you put the meta tag for view port? This is simple example - <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

Answer (score 1):

It's not referring to your screen size, but actually the window size. You can trigger those events either by rescaling your window with your mouse or by pressing "ctrl" and "+" or "ctrl" and "-". So for a resolution higher than 1000 you will have a background orange, for 800 and higher a background green, and for 500 and higher a background of blue;.